# How to get TeamViewer to ask for a password everytime when connecting to a remote machine?

Tags: security, teamviewer

TeamViewer has a convenience feature where it automatically fills in the password from a previous session, so you only have to press the Logon button to connect.  I don't like this behavior and is there a way to disable this feature, so that you have to enter the password everytime?

EDIT:

I am using TeamViewer Portable v9.0.24951.

Comment: Disable this on your machine or on people who connect to your machine?

Comment: On my machine.  You never know what could happen if the machine is left unattended.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this available for the portable version, but I found it on my current version as I just noticed that. If you're using this on a machine used by other people that's a pretty big security flaw where it remembers the last machine and the password to automatically reconnect to it.

Choose extra > options at the top.

Go into advanced options > show advanced options > Uncheck temporarily save connection passwords

I believe that should fix your issue.

Comment: Looks like this works, wanna add that you have to sign out / sign in after changing this.

Answer (score 2):

For TeamViewer portable version 9.x and 10.x (at least the Android version) under in Options under Security has "Remember history passwords".  Uncheck it.

If you don't see it, upgrade to the latest version.

For the Desktop version, you can clear it manually by attempting a connection and when presented with the filled in password dialogue, fill it with something that isn't your password and try and connect.  It will then forget your password.  This works in Windows and will probably work on other Desktop platforms.

Comment: Do you know whether the OP's version also has this?  Is your suggestion to check whether it's there and if not, upgrade to the current version?

Comment: No, so I inferred that since this was posted 2014, it was probably version 9 or 10.  If it is earlier, then it may be there but it may not.  If not, then he would have to update.  There have been many bug fixes since then so an update would probably be advisable anyway.  If the OP has another OS, then this may help, or it may not depending on how similar the UI is on different OSs.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other answers aren't really answering your question. As I understand it, basically, you want to keep your teamviewer computers signed in...but when you connect to another computer that you own (that's in your computers & contacts list), you want teamviewer to prompt you for that computer's teamviewer password. I wanted the same thing...because leaving all your computers accessible without a password prompt to anyone that has access to any of your other computers is very insecure...

Well, I figured it out (Teamviwer 10.0.47484):

You must do the following From EACH computer you wish to require a password prompt for, because it won't allow you to change these settings except through the local computer's teamviewer application (though you can connect to the remote computers via teamviewer and change them individually through the remote connection).

1. Sign in on EACH computer using your Teamviewer account username & password.
2. Inside EACH computer's teamviewer Computer's & Contacts window, you must find your currently signed in computer. It should say "(this computer)" next to your computer's name.
3. Click the little down arrow to the right of the computer's name, and a window will drop down. In the top right of that window, select the little gear icon, and choose "properties".
4. Delete the saved password in the top right input box (you should just see bullet points if there is a password saved, and nothing if there is no password saved).
5. Click "OK". Wait a few seconds for the settings to sync up across all your teamviewer computers.
6. From another computer with teamviewer signed in, you should now be able to click on the computer you want to connect to...and teamviewer will prompt you for the password because it is no longer saved.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After opening TeamViewer, after it already automatically signed you in, in the "Computer & Contacts" windows, click the down arrow next to your name on the top right section, then click "Sign Out" (As seen below).

[image]

In the "Computers & Contacts" window, you should see the area to sign in. Below that, there is a "Keep me signed in" check box. Un-check this box and sign in (as seen below). You should no longer be automatically signed in. Please note that these directions are based on the TeamViewer version 9.0.24951.

[image: Un-check "keep me signed in" check box]

Comment: I have never signed in and the Keep me signed in is unchecked.  I am beginning to think this only happens with portable version.

Comment: I didn't see where you mentioned it was on a portable device. Which device are you running TeamViewer on? I now realize you are running it on TeamViewer portable, but what type of device are you running it on?

Comment: I am running it on Windows7.

Answer (score 1):

From above descriptions and discussions, this seems you are using unattended password instead of random generated password.

To disable this (in server side):
Extras > Options > Security > Remove any password in "Personal password (for unattended access)"

If you want extra security, you may consider "whitelist" in the same page which only allow particular hardware to access to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the keep me signed in box

Comment: I am not signed in though.

Comment: He means the screen you get after you type a PC's partner ID

Comment: There is no such screen.  The password dialog appears and there is no option for that.

Comment: Not in this case.  The password persists until the program is closed.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Mavericks, TeamViewer 9.0.31181 what worked for me was under Partner ID > unfold > clear this history.

Firstly it forgets ID, and if you enter it again it has forgotten the password.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the properties and delete the password from there, every time some body else who is connected to you will have to give your personnel password to have the access, hope it will 
help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on version 12.0.71503 Free.

On each computer do the following...

1. Extras
2. Options
3. Advanced
4. Show Advanced Options
5. Advanced settings for connections to OTHER computers
6. Uncheck 'Temporarily save connection passwords'